# Transformar array do json em array do php

Tags: php, json, array

Bom, eu estou com um pequeno problema que eu ainda não consegui resolver. Já procurei no Google sobre isso, e as soluções que encontrei não serviram no meu problema.

Preciso transformar a array "Players" que está nesse JSON: http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list em uma Array do PHP.

```
{
  "Status": true,
  "Players": {
    "online": 8,
    "max": 60,
    "list":["Uchoa","zMarvado","Diego_Dias_BR_RJ","Konotero","Zirak_","Grafite07","MateusInox","Stevegamer138"]
  },
  "Version": "1.8.8"
}
```

Esse é o código que eu tou usando, sugerido pelas respostas abaixo:

```
<?php

$lista = file_get_contents("http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list");

$infor = json_decode($lista);

$players = $infor['Players'];
$players_list = $players['list'];

foreach($players_list as $i){
  echo $i;
}

?>
```

O erro está na variavel `$players`, segundo o `PHP`:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /customers/6/8/7/craftlite.com.br/httpd.www/test.php on line 8
```

Eu não entendo muito de PHP, sou mais habituado ao Java, por isso eu não sei identificar os erros daqui.

Comment: json_decode com true retorna um array, então tu não deveria acessar a propriedade list e sim algo do tipo $players  = $infor['Players']['list']. Caso isso não resolva posta aí o resultado de var_dump($infor)

Comment: A dump é essa: _array(3) { ["Status"]=> bool(true) ["Players"]=> array(3) { ["online"]=> int(7) ["max"]=> int(60) ["list"]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(5) "Uchoa" [1]=> string(10) "MateusInox" [2]=> string(8) "zMarvado" [3]=> string(8) "fullsets" [4]=> string(13) "Stevegamer138" [5]=> string(16) "Diego_Dias_BR_RJ" [6]=> string(8) "Konotero" } } ["Version"]=> string(5) "1.8.8" }_

Comment: Brunno, nunca coloque apenas o link para algo essencial na sua pergunta, pois caso ele se perca, não será possível ela ajudar também outras pessoas, fugindo assim do propósito do fórum!!! =)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, infelizmente eu já modifiquei a pagina test.php, mas na próxima eu posto o erro no próprio tópico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você tenta executar

```
$infor->Players->list;
```

vocês está tentando acessar um `Objeto`.

Mas como você está lendo um `Objeto` `Json`, você deveria ler da seguinte forma:

```
$players = $infor["Players"];
$players_list = $players["list"]
```

E ler a lista:

```
foreach($players_list as $i){
    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: Opa, vou incrementar o código com isso, marco resolvido se me ajudar!

Comment: Surgiu um novo erro, editei a pergunta!

Comment: O erro foi panguice minha, agora está funcionando direitinho!

Answer (score 1):

Para poder acessar desta forma:

```
$infor->Players->list;
```

você precisa remover o segundo parâmetro `true`:

```
$infor = json_decode($lista);
```

Caso contrário, ele irá converter em um array associativo, e terá que acessá-lo assim:

```
$players = $infor["Players"]["list"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Se na função json_decode for passado o parâmetro true, o json_decode retorna um array associativo.

```
$lista = file_get_contents("http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list");
$infor = json_decode($lista,true);
$players = $infor['Players']['list'];

foreach ($players as $player) {
     echo ' '.$player.',';
}
```

Se na função json_decode não for passado o parâmetro true, o json_decode retorna um Objeto.

```
$lista = file_get_contents("http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list");
$infor = json_decode($lista);  
$players = $infor->Players->list;

foreach ($players as $player) {
    echo ' '.$player.',';
}
```

[Referência php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Vi que você não colocou o `;` no final do `file_get_contents`.

```
<?php
$lista = file_get_contents("http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list") <-
$infor = json_decode($lista, true);
$players = $infor->Players->list;
echo = "$players";
?>
```

Comment: Realmente rsrs, percebi isso há alguns minutos atrás

Comment: Deu certo agora?

Comment: Não, não era esse o problema. mas agora está resolvido

Answer (score 0):

O erro que eu tinha foi resolvido da seguinte maneira:

Segui os passos do `Hugo Fernandes` e do `Kenny Rafael`, porém eu fiz confusão e acabou dando outro erro. Vamos por partes, visando ajudar outros que vão usar dessa pergunta para ajudar em seus problemas:

Onde estava meu erro? No começo, o código estava assim:

```
<?php
$lista = file_get_contents("http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list")
$infor = json_decode($lista, true);
$players = $infor->Players->list;
echo = "$players";
?>
```

Já da pra notar uma série de erros na sintaxe, como a falta de `;` após o atributo do `$lista`, e o `=` após o `echo` (echo não é uma variável, então não da pra botar valor no echo).

Ok, reformando o código, ele fica mais certinho:

```
<?php
$lista = file_get_contents("http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list"); //Botei o ;
$infor = json_decode($lista, true);
$players = $infor->Players->list;
echo "$players";//Tirei o = 
?>
```

A partir daí, já notamos o erro bruto:

Como disse o `Hugo Fernandes`, eu estou tentando acessar um `Objeto`, sendo que o meu objetivo era acessar uma lista de `Objetos` (Uma `Array`).

Beleza, eu fiz o que ele sugeriu na resposta dele, então o código ficou assim:

```
<?php

$lista = file_get_contents("http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list");

$infor = json_decode($lista);

$players = $infor['Players'];
$players_list = $players['list'];

foreach($players_list as $i){
   echo ' '.$i.',';
}

?>
```

Porém, ai que surgiu a confusão. Eu li as respostas "correndo" e acabei fazendo caca. o `Kenny Rafael` disse que eu deveria acessar sem o parâmetro `true` para acessar o `Objeto`, e ai que surgiu o segundo erro: Eu tentei acessar uma ``` JSON``Array ``` a partir de um ``` JSON``Object ```, e acabou dando o erro:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /customers/6/8/7/craftlite.com.br/httpd.www/test.php on line 8
```

Eu fiquei um tempo lendo as respostas e consegui me orientar. Eu me liguei que deveria colocar o parâmetro `true` no `json_decode`, transformando a variável `$infor` em uma `JSON Array`, ao invez de um `JSON Object`, então o código ficou assim:

```
<?php

$lista = file_get_contents("http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list");

$infor = json_decode($lista, true);

$players = $infor['Players'];
$players_list = $players['list'];

foreach($players_list as $i){
  echo ' '.$i.',';
}

?>
```

Depois da ajuda desses dois mestres, e de um pouquinho mais de atenção, eu concluí o código sem erros!

Answer (score 0):

Faz esse teste aqui que vc vai entender :D

```
$json_url = "http://mcapi.ca/query/ip.craftlite.com.br:25571/list";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```